# COUNTIF with partial match and wildcards

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a partial match COUNTIF (G Sheets) that pulls in a wildcard + a specific character (~) + a cell reference.  For example xxxxxx~J28~xxxxxx.

I tried both:
"*"&""&"~"&J28&"~"&""&"*" and
"*"&"~"&J28&"~"&"*"

I have used the partial match COUNTIF before ("*"&J28&"*") but not with the addition of this middle character.

Comment: Post a few of your sample data then show your desired output.

Comment: Here is the sheet.  I am trying to isolate the COUNTIF to find the second name.  
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cPjwm6N8JT5qYlLZI_qbzdJlI-nPErqDIgzMwYSCVT8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try my answer and let us know your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the treatment of "~". It can be used in front of `?` or `*` to actually search for those characters rather than wildcards. Therefore the second one where you have `~*` is literally searching for an `*`, which you don't have.

The following formula returns the results you expect:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$4, "*~"&D2&"~~*")
```

Note that I put the `~` twice at the end to literally look for the `~` and not a `*`, which is what `~*` does.

Answer (score 0):

You need `REGEXEXTRACT()` function. I have included `MAP()` function to make it dynamic spill results. Try-

```
=MAP(D2:D4,LAMBDA(t,COUNTIFS(MAP(B2:B4,LAMBDA(x,REGEXEXTRACT(x,"~([^\~]+)"))),t)))
```

[image]